# StreamWriter path specify with up one or more levels

Tags: c#, stream

How to specify path for StreamWriter with up two level:

As an example project located at D:\Projects\ffp\bin\Debug> need to do cd ../../ and then save in LOG directory means like D:\Projects\ffp\LOG\test.txt

I try do describe - no matter what path is would be always need to save in two levels higher.

Comment: You can just do that, `new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Log\text.txt")`. But don't, and take a look at log4net.

Comment: Look at what? Please do describe - because if you mean Logging platform you are wrong. It's just save a flat file(not log)

Comment: He ment look at [log4net logging framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net)

Answer (score 1):

CodeCaster's comment should be correct...

new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Log\filename.log")

Should go back/down two directories and then forward/up into the "Log" folder. I do not believe the folder will be created automatically.

Use the Exist and CreateDirectory methods off the Directory object if you need to create the folder first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx